# Dart/Flutter question for increase value in listview.builder

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I have a listview and a button on each card, how can I do that if the button is clicked only the cards BELOW increase in value?, for value in the card I use a dynamic list...

Comment: Did you render all cards in listview corresponding to a List of models?. If yes then just update value of model in next index and call setState() method in your statefull widget.

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that produce the issue you are facing or the thing you've tried so far